# Flutter Custom SideBar Not Taking Full Height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, sidebar

I am working on a custom sidebar for my app since I dont like the default drawer that flutter comes with.
Everything works fine, that is, the sidebar takes the entire height of the mobile phone [image: Flull height sidebar before I rendered home contents]

until I render the page contents along the sidebar as shown below
[image: Sidebar height breaks after I render the main home contents]

Here's the Main contents code:

```
import 'package:api_example_app/LandingScreen/components/control_button.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/LandingScreen/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/charts/GasChart.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/charts/HumChart.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/charts/MoisChart.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/charts/NurChart.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/charts/PhChart.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/charts/TemChart.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/charts/chartComponents/HumCard.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/SensorScreen/components/sensor_screen.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class LandingScreenBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandingScreenBodyState createState() => _LandingScreenBodyState();
}

class _LandingScreenBodyState extends State<LandingScreenBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.05),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.1),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'ngDAQ',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 25,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.01),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'The ngDAQ is a Smart Agriculture solution based on IoT, seeking to increase farm productivity by automation and monitoring.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: kDarkGreyColor, fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.temperatureHigh,
                  title: 'Tem',
                  subtitle: '33C',
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new TemChart()));
                  },
                ),
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  title: 'Hum ',
                  subtitle: '75%',
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.cloudShowersHeavy,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new HumChart()));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.hourglass,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new MoisChart()));
                  },
                  title: 'Mos',
                  subtitle: '40',
                ),
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  title: 'PH ',
                  subtitle: '14',
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.meteor,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PhChart()));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.leaf,
                  title: 'Nur',
                  subtitle: 'Good',
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new NurChart()));
                  },
                ),
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  title: 'Gas ',
                  subtitle: 'Good',
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.flask,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new GasChart()));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
            // DefaultButton(
            //   size: size,
            //   title: "Next",
            //   press: () {
            //     Navigator.push(
            //       context,
            //       CupertinoPageRoute(
            //         builder: (context) => SensorScreen(),
            //       ),
            //     );
            //   },
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Heres' the Sidebar Code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
// import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import '../../constants.dart';

class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  // const SideBar({Key ? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SideBarState createState() => _SideBarState();
}

class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<SideBar> {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  StreamController<bool> isSidebarOpenedStreamController;
  Stream<bool> isSidebarOpenedStream;
  StreamSink<bool> isSidebarOpenedSink;

  // final bool isSidebarOpened = true;
  final _animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _animationDuration);
    isSidebarOpenedStreamController = PublishSubject<bool>();
    isSidebarOpenedStream = isSidebarOpenedStreamController.stream;
    isSidebarOpenedSink = isSidebarOpenedStreamController.sink;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    isSidebarOpenedStreamController.close();
    isSidebarOpenedSink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onIconPressed() {
    final animationStatus = _animationController.status;
    final isAnimationCompleted = animationStatus == AnimationStatus.completed;

    if (isAnimationCompleted) {
      isSidebarOpenedSink.add(false);
      _animationController.reverse();
    } else {
      isSidebarOpenedSink.add(true);
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
      initialData: false,
      stream: isSidebarOpenedStream,
      builder: (context, isSideBarOpenedAsync) {
        return AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: _animationDuration,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : 0,
          right: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : screenWidth - 45,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: kOrangeColor,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0, -0.9),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    onIconPressed();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 35,
                    height: 80,
                    color: kOrangeColor,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: AnimatedIcon(
                      progress: _animationController.view,
                      icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The Layout Where the render is done:

```
import 'package:api_example_app/LandingScreen/components/body.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../constants.dart';
import 'sidebar.dart';

class SideBarLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  // const SideBarLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          LandingScreenBody(),
          SideBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I dont know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Inside SideBar, you need to surround it with `Container` widget, and set its height to `double.infinity`;

```
//Inside SideBar
return Container(
      width: 200,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: StreamBuilder<bool> (
           ...
      );
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But, it thru another error:  Exception caught by widgets library. 
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.  This is how I used it:   `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
        initialData: false,
        stream: isSidebarOpenedStream, `

Comment: And, the open and close sidebar icon wouldn't respond too

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks to @eyoeldefare.
From the main home, where I returned padding, I [return container instead, then, add:

```
return Container(
  height: double.infinity,
   (
       ...
  ),
```

);